# How can I connect to SQL Server directly from Android with an C++ Builder FMX application

Tags: sql-server, firemonkey, c++builder, builder

I get the following error when I try to connect to SQL Server directly with a C++Builder 10.2 Tokyo application. I couldn't locate the library requested despite all my searching.

Can anyone help? I'm at a crossroad to decide to continue with C++Builder or Xamarin.

[image]

Comment: Well, you'll find very few examples, and no official Microsoft support for connecting directly to SQL Server from C++ without the normal ODBC or OleDb drivers, which are only avialable on Windows, Linux, and MacOS.  If this is your plan, you should strongly favor Xamarin, or interpose some sort of web or RPC API that runs on a platform with supported drivers (JDBC, ODBC, or .NET).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have C++ Builder Enterprise or Architect edition? You need this to connect to SQL Server using FireDAC. C++ Builder Professional edition can only connect to local databases.

Comment: I have Enterprise edition and I did try to use FireDAC , it works on Windows applications but doesnt work on Android

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this page:
[Embarcadero Microsoft SQL interface](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Connect_to_Microsoft_SQL_Server_(FireDAC))

suggests to me that Microsoft SQL with Android client is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

FDConnection is FMX compatible, but the drivers for various OSes are not.

There's a company called Devart that develops direct access connectivity for RAD studio mobile devices; Not sure if this will work if you only have C++ builder; but worth a try;

I'm currently in the same pickle and I'm busy writing a tcpclient/server proxy fmx app that will run on a windows server[where the mssql driver will work]

The idea is to connect from mobile device with tcp client to tcp server component running on windows and have that app grab the info i need for mobile app. Not the fastest solution in long run as you have to do all your authentication and encryption yourself and not the cheapest either as it requires an online windows server or pc... but if you already have it, you might as well use it.

Will update if it succeeds or fails